# How does client-machine/browser handle unrequested HTTP response?

Tags: http, tcp

Imagine the following:

- User goes to script (`http://sample.org/test.php`),
- Script sends an HTTP request to some other page (`http://google.com/`). For this example, we'll say using `curl`.
- The script sets the IP address of the request to the user's IP, via `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`.

I know already that the requesting script will not receive the response, as the remote-host will send any responses to the IP address given in the request.

What I am wondering is what happens to this response? Assuming the client is on a LAN that has one external address and that all traffic sent to that IP is handled by a router acting as a DHCP server, will the response even get back to the user's machine? If it did, would there be any way to ensure that it was handled by the user's browser? And if so, how would the browser handle this, typically? Would it open a new window with Google in it?

I definitely have a follow up to this question, but I am very curious what goes on at this level, before I experiment further.

Comment: A http server will not send a response to another IP address (or on another TCP connection for that matter). What makes you think it does ?

Comment: @nos - I know it won't send to another IP address. It will send to the IP address given in the request. I was wondering what happens to responses sent to an IP address when the *requester* has changed the IP address to an IP other than its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - The script sets the IP address of the request to the user's IP, via CURLOPT_INTERFACE.

Usually, this won't work. Your ISP knows which IP address you are supposed to have and will not forward traffic coming from "fake" IP addresses.

In particular, since you can only communicate one-way with a fake IP (since the answer won't reach you), you would not be able to establish a working TCP connection, since TCP requires a [three-way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_handshake). Thus, you wouldn't be able to submit your web request.

> What I am wondering is what happens to this response? Assuming the client is on a LAN that has one external address and that all traffic sent to that IP is handled by a router acting as a DHCP server, will the response even get back to the user's machine?

If the user's PC has an internal IP address and uses NAT, the router will not know which LAN machine to forward the packet to (since it did not see any *outgoing* request to which it could match that response). Therefore, the answer would be dropped.

Even *if* you could get the response to reach the client:

> If it did, would there be any way to ensure that it was handled by the user's browser?

No. As stated above, a TCP request consists of a three-way handshake. This handshake has not been completed, so the operating system would just drop the packet.

Answer (score 2):

`CURLOPT_INTERFACE` is for use on computers that have multiple IP addresses assigned to them, to specify which of those addresses should be used as the source IP for the connection.  You can't use it to spoof some *other* computer's IP address.  Most likely you'll either get an error, or the option will be ignored and the OS will choose a source interface automatically (the default behavior).

The response will be returned on the same TCP connection as the request.

Comment: what makes you think you can't create an interface that uses another machine's IP on the LAN?

Comment: The question was about a PHP script trying to spoof arbitrary clients' IPs when making new outgoing connections, so that the remote end sends packets directly back to the original client rather than to the host where the PHP script is running.  It'd be possible to make that happen in a contrived scenario involving duplicated IPs on a LAN, but in real-world use-cases it will not work.